# import dataset automaticly in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataset `my.df <- read_excel("C:/Users/Seyma/Docs/DF_05_04_2023.xlsx")` that belongs the day before. Each day I receive the same dataset based on the previous day (except on weekends and Italian national holidays). I would like to update the `my.df` without changing the directory manually (such as 05_05_2023). is there a way to get around this? many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Sys.Date` and `strftime` to generate the file name:

```r
strftime(Sys.Date() - 1, 'C:/Users/Seyma/Docs/DF_%m_%d_%Y.xlsx')
#> [1] "C:/Users/Seyma/Docs/DF_05_04_2023.xlsx"
```

Tomorrow, the same code will produce `"C:/Users/Seyma/Docs/DF_05_05_2023.xlsx"`

So an automated version of your code would be

```r
my.df <- strftime(Sys.Date() - 1, 'C:/Users/Seyma/Docs/DF_%m_%d_%Y.xlsx') |>
           read_excel()
```